# windows clients in local network are losing connection to samba shares on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, windows, samba, file-sharing

I am facing a problem which I am not able to resolve until now with any help I got on net from forums etc.

I have a network which has 7 Ubuntu machines and 3 Windows machines

Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS and 2 Windows are on 8.1 and one on Windows 7

one of the Ubuntu desktop I am trying to convert as a file server for all.

the folder which I wanted to share i shared it via right click - properties - local network share

in `smb.conf` I shared my home directories as browsable, guest ok, and create and directory mask 0775.

All computers are on same workgroup.

All Ubuntu machines are working perfectly fine.

Windows machines are also able to see the computer on network and shares on computer.

Windows pc can connect to the samba share but loses the connection after a while which then is unable to connect.

I have to log off from the Windows pc and log in again but same problem persists

It shows the message that you may not have access to this network resource

or no such file or directory exist

or invalid name or directory.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the issue was the conflict of two similar services based on same components.

the components here being samba and two conflicting services being samba share and nautilus share.

those who have tried to share the directories etc through built-in GUI of the properties window of a directory will at first instance prompt to install a service saying service is not installed.

looked into details it downloads samba common etc.

it works perfectly well in linux only network.

however it will face trouble if network have windows clients as well.
MS Windows will specifically look for samba share configured through '/etc/samba/smb.conf'.

If that is configured MS windows will have no problem but linux machines will not be able to connect detecting two overlapping services on same platform for same purpose. conflict to choose a process: nautilus share or samba share.

the simple and logical solution is to unshare everything done/shared through nautilus share (using built in sharing in GUI window for properties of the shared directory.

given the smb.conf is written well there should not be any problem.

this is the finding of and simple solution to my mind boggling struggle.

hope this will serve to any help.